MATLAB, how to read index phase after plotting the curve?
Now I'm doing an experiment by plotting the results of radar detection with phase output. I get the phase wave image, but the problem is how to read the phase change if I only have the information from the plot image? (the plot I get is obtained from excel data from radar detection results).
% Load data from CSV file
data = csvread(phase data from csv);

% Unwrap phase data
x_w = unwrap(data);

% Convert phase to distance (in millimeters)
lambda = 3e8/24e9; % Wavelength
x_conv = 100 * x_w * lambda / (2 * pi); % Conversion to mm

% Low-pass filtering
[b, a] = butter(4, [0.01]); % Butterworth filter
x_filter = filter(b, a, x_conv); % Filtered data

% Plot filtered data
figure(1);
plot(x_filter);
hold on;


i really clueless abt how to read the change in phasa, please help me. I need the result shown in index
